# Upload 1Gb file through Logic app using sftp-ssh to Azure File share

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-files

I am using the Logic App to upload 1 Gb file as below-
Trigger - When files are added or modified (properties only)
Action1 - Get file content
Action 2- Create file(Azure fileshare)
Till 35 MB all triggers and actions works fine. After the file uploaded in SFTP crosses 40 MB, SFTP-SSH trigger and action all works fine. But while the workflow moves to the second action - 'Create File': it fails with the below error The specified resource may be in use by an SMB client'. When I see the Azure file share storage account, I see filename.partial.lock getting created. I modified the access policy as well, but the issue persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Logic apps are not designed to upload or download the large amount data from source/destination, its a workflow solution which you can design to provide solution your business need, however you can still use chunk upload functionality in logic-app to upload or download large file via logic app.
please refer 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#set-up-chunking

Answer (score 1):

To upload large file, make sure enable the `Allow chunking`.

From your description, suppose it should be `SharingViolation`, you could check the [error codes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-error-codes).

And in the official doc, there are two scenario to get the Sharing Violation error:

**Sharing Violation Due to File Access**

- Client A opens the file with FileAccess.Write and FileShare.Read
  (denies subsequent Write/Deletewhile open).
- Client B then opens the file with FileAccess.Write with
  FileShare.Write (denies subsequent Read/Delete while open).
- Result: Client B encounters a sharing violation since it specified a
  file access that is denied by the share mode specified previously by
  Client A.

**Sharing Violation Due to Share Mode**

- Client A opens the file with FileAccess.Write and FileShare.Write
  (denies subsequent Read/Delete while open).
- Client B then opens the file with FileAccess.Write with
  FileShare.Read (denies subsequent Write/Delete while open).
- Result: Client B encounters a sharing violation since it specified a
  share mode that denies write access to a file that is still open for
  write access.

These are scenario you need to consider, another choice you could try to use the REST API to upload the file and in the HTTP action set the `Allow chunking`.

Answer (score 0):

I think one more way to resolve the issue is redesign which could be more scale-able solution:

1. Use logic app to get notification if file is added or modified on SFTP/FTP location.
   once the file is added read the file path for that file.
2. Create Service bus message and send the file Path to Service Bus message as message content.
3. Create Service Bus queue message trigger Azure function which listen to those message (created in step 2) 
   Azure function will read the Chunk of files from SFTP using the file path.

this way you can read or write more then 30 GB file.
this solution will be more scale able solution as azure function and auto scale on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. The reason for the error 'The specified resource may be in use by an SMB client' is due to the mounting of the file share with two Linux Virtual machines. We unmounted the Linux VMs and did fresh single mounting. The error got fixed with that.

Answer (score 0):

MSFT has confirmed in our discussion that "Create File share" has a limitation of 100 or 300 MB. It was just able to work with SFTP as data arrives in chunk. MSFT is working further to give proper error statement, when the file size is beyond 100 or 300 MB. Below is quoted from MSFT email-
"Thanks for the details , actually the Product team confirm to me that your flow is working by luck , it should not work with this sizes an they are working to implement the limits correctly to prevent files larger than maximum size which is maybe 300 or 100 “I am not yet sure ”
And this strange behavior is only happing when we are reading the content from SFTP chucked. 
"